# Restrict access to a controller based on certain criteria not user authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-5

What is the correct way to restrict access to a controller?

For instance, I might have "ProductReviewController", I want to be able to check that this controller is accessible in the current store and is enabled. I'm not after the code to do that but am interested in the approach to stopping the user getting to the controller should this criteria not be met. I would like the request to just carry on as if the controller was never there (so perhaps throwing a 404).

My thoughts so far:

1. A data annotation i.e `[IsValidController]`. Which `Attribute` class would I derive from - Authorize doesn't really seem to fit and I would associate this with user authentication. Also, I'm not sure what the correct response would be if the criteria wasn't met (but I guess this would depend on the `Attribute` it's deriving from). I could put this data annotation against my base controller.
2. Find somewhere lower down in the page life cycle and stop the user hitting the controller at all if the controller doesn't meet my criteria. i.e Create my own controller factory as depicted in point 7 here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunm/archive/2013/10/03/understanding-of-mvc-page-life-cycle.aspx

What is the best approach for this?

Note: At the moment, I am leaning towards option 1 and using `AuthorizeAttribute` with something like the code below. I feel like I am misusing the `AuthorizeAttribute` though.

```
public class IsControllerAccessible : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (!CriteriaMet())
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
        new RouteValueDictionary(
            new
            {
                controller = "Generic",
                action = "404"
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused about `AuthorizeAttribute`. It is an Action Filter, not a Data Annotation. Data Annotations decorate model properties for validatioj, Action Filter's decorate controller actions to examine the controller's context and doing something before the action executes.

So, restricting access to a controller action is the raison d'etre of the `AuthorizeAttribute`, so let's use it!

With the help of the good folks of SO, I created a customer Action Filter that restricted access to actions (and even controllers) based on being part of an Access Directory group:

```
public class AuthorizeADAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Groups { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
        {
            /* Return true immediately if the authorization is not 
            locked down to any particular AD group */
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Groups))
                return true;

            // Get the AD groups
            var groups = Groups.Split(',').ToList<string>();

            // Verify that the user is in the given AD group (if any)
            var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURADCONTROLLER");
            var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context,
                                                 IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                                                 httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.Name, group))
                        return true;
                }
                catch (NoMatchingPrincipalException exc)
                {
                    var msg = String.Format("While authenticating a user, the operation failed due to the group {0} could not be found in Active Directory.", group);
                    System.ApplicationException e = new System.ApplicationException(msg, exc);
                    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
                    return false;
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    var msg = "While authenticating a user, the operation failed.";
                    System.ApplicationException e = new System.ApplicationException(msg, exc);
                    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note this will return a `401 Unauthorized`, which makes sense, and not the `404 Not Found` you indicated above.

Now, the magic in this is you can restrict access by applying it at the action level:

```
[AuthorizeAD(Groups = "Editor,Contributer")]
public ActionResult Create()
```

Or at the controller level:

```
[AuthorizeAD(Groups = "Admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
```

Or even globally by editing `FilterConfig.cs` in `/App_Start':

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new Code.Filters.MVC.AuthorizeADAttribute() { Groups = "User, Editor, Contributor, Admin" });
    }
```

Complete awesome sauce!

P.S. You mention page lifecycle in your second point. There is no such thing in MVC, at least not in the Web Forms sense you might be thinking. That's a good thing to my mind, as things are greatly simplified, and I don't have to remember a dozen or so different lifecycle events and what the heck each one of them is raised for!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification on data annotations - Got my terminology wrong there. I have just written my own version using the `AuthorizeAttribute` and it's working well. I just wanted to make sure this is the correct way. When I mentioned the life cycle, I was referring to this kind of thing: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunm/archive/2013/10/03/understanding-of-mvc-page-life-cycle.aspx. I was specifically thinking of overriding  point 7 and creating a custom controller factory.

Comment: p.s `404 not found` would be the correct response in my case. It's not the user who wouldn't be unauthorised but the site that shouldn't be showing the content (which means the user followed a cached link or something).

Comment: Then the code should probably reside in your controller itself, since it is responsible for supplying the correct view based on user interaction. If the user supplies a product id, have the controller check for its existence in the store, and if it does not, redirect to a particular view indicating such.